# Is there a way to populate a slot in a grandparent component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, inertiajs

Giving these 3 components `Layout > Index > Child` where `Index` populates `Layouts'` `default` slot and `Child` is used somewhere in `Index` (or nested in `Index`), is there a way for `Layout` to have a second named slot where `Index` and/or `Child` can have a named template for that slot?

Example:

```vue
// Layout.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <header>...</header>

        <main>
            <!-- Index.vue is rendered here -->
            <slot />
        </main>

        <aside>
            <!-- A named templated from a child of the default slot should be rendered here -->
            <slot name="optional-aside" />
        </aside>

        <footer>...</footer>
    </div>
</template>
```

```vue
// Index.vue
<template>
    <div>
        ...

        <Child>...</Child>
    </div>
</template>

// This is inertiajs specific so i don't need to wrap each "Index" page component in <Layout>
// This is typically done in app.js together with createApp, 
// i'm just putting it here to show that there is a connection from index to Layout, although this is also valid
<script>
import Layout from './Layout.vue';
export default {
    layout: Layout
}
</script>
```

```vue
// Child.vue
<template>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
    <template #optional-aside>
        ...
    </template>
</template>
```

More info:
I use inertiaJs and have Layout configured "globally" for all pages, but on some pages I want to be able to populate other slots in the layout. I know I can disable the auto layout for those pages and do a traditional component structure, but that would only work if the named template is in the `Index.vue` file (unless I add a slot there and create a mess of nested slots)

Temporary Solution (not ideal but kinda works)

```vue
// Layout.vue
<template>
    ...
        <aside>
            <!-- A named templated from Child.vue should be rendered here -->
            <div id="optional-aside" />
        </aside>
    ...
</template>
```

```vue
// OptionalAside.vue
<template>
    <teleport v-if="shouldTeleport" to='#optional-aside'>
        <slot/>
    </teleport>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

// Delay teleport as when this component is rendered before Layout
const shouldTeleport = ref(false);
onMounted(() => {
    shouldTeleport.value = true;
})
</script>
```

I can then use the OptionalAside component anywhere as deep as I want, the problem is:

1. this feels messy and is prone to errors.
2. I want more control in vue, maybe receive props from layout (which i can use provide/inject for

Here is where the magic of `Layout` comes from https://inertiajs.com/pages#creating-layouts

Comment: You will have problems with teleport in SSR as far as I remember, teleport works well out of `<div id="__nuxt">` and dynamically generated elements there.

Comment: I don't use nuxt. i havent even tested my method with ssr, but i dont see why it wont work as the issue i was having with teleport was it was trying to teleport before dom nodes were created. by pushing that to the mounted hook, all dom nodes (i think) already exist. Unless teleport has other issues in ssr?

Comment: Oh, yeah, no Nuxt. Well, if you don't need SSR, teleport will work fine for you. And there is no other better way right now.